# Why do JavaScript multiple async/awaits behave differently when it awaits promises vs when it awaits functions returning promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, v8

I have the below code with both the implementations.

```js
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 1');
  }, 1000);
});

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 2');
  }, 1000);
})

const p1func = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 1 func');
  }, 1000);
});

const p2func = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 2 func');
  }, 1000);
})

async function TestPromise() {
  console.log("started");
  const val = await p1;
  console.log(val);

  const val2 = await p2;
  console.log(val2);
  //checkpoint 1: reaches this point in 1 second
  const val3 = await p1func();
  console.log(val3);

  const val4 = await p2func();
  console.log(val4);
  //from checkpoint 1, it takes 2 seconds to reach here
}

TestPromise();
```

When I ran the code I noticed that when js awaits 2 promises, it starts executing them in parallel & completes within 1 second (asynchronously). When the functions returning promises were run JS ran them one by one (synchronously). Is JS engine detecting 2 awaits on promises prior run in order to be able to execute them in parallel? Why can't it do the same with functions returning promises?

Comment: `p1` and `p2` start immediately, `p1func` and `p2func` only when you call them.

Comment: For the first two (the plain Promise objects), the timers start **immediately** when you create the Promise instances. The `await` calls don't have anything to do with *starting* those; they start because you told the runtime to start them when you created the Promises.  On the other hand, the Promise instances in the functions are not created until the functions are called.

Comment: Looking for an applicable duplicate, but... The `Promise` *starts* when it's created, not when it's awaited.  In the first example you create both and then await them in turn.  In the second example you don't create the second one until after you've awaited the first one.  The two examples behave differently because they're doing different things.

Comment: The function you pass to the Promise constructor executes synchronously, not asynchronously. So all the `setTimeout()` calls happen immediately one after the other.